# Windows equivalent for Unix's pdfinfo

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

Is there a Windows equivalent for Unix's [`pdfinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfinfo)?
I need to get the page count of a PDF document in PHP.
I tried with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) 'identify' command, but seems it is not very efficient.

Answer (score 9):

Precompiled binaries are available at
http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

Answer (score 2):

Try [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/)

> cpdf.exe -pages file.pdf

which will print the number of pages to standard output. It should be pretty fast.

Comment: It also prints "For non-commercial use only" on the output, which is quite annoying, even if you only want the number of pages.